# In Realm on Android, How do you migrate (add) a new linking field

Tags: android, migration, realm

Ok so i have an app than had a Coin realm object. I am now upgrading my app, and adding multiple new fields to the existing Coin object. So far so good, but how do i migrate a LinkingObject, RealmResults type. linkedPortfolioCoins is what i want to migrate

```
public class Coin extends RealmObject {
    //a bunch of other fields here

    @LinkingObjects("coin")
    private final RealmResults<PortfolioCoin> linkedPortfolioCoins = null;
}
```

Also, There is only

```
.addRealmListField
```

Which i assume will be ok instead of RealmResults, but how do i make it a LinkingObject to Coin.

The error im getting is

```
 Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field count is more than expected - expected 18 but was 19
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok just to help anyone in future. It appears you dont have to migrate linking objects. Got it working by just not migrating the linkedPortfolioCoins and leaving it out. That would also explain my error :)

Comment: Yup, you don't need to add `@LinkingObjects` to the schema, they are automatically created if you have existing links. You just need to create the field to access them. (I can't seem to find the post I'd want to cite for it, but it's kinda true.)